# Sorting Arrays from a file in C

Tags: c, file, sorting, compare

I am trying to sort from a file student's information. Their information consists of first name, last name and id number. I already sorted the students by their last name. I did this by comparing their names by swapping them around. The result I got was that the last name and corresponding first name is sorted however, the student's corresponding id number still remained unsorted after swapping the id numbers as well. May I have some assistance please. Thanks in advance.

**Sorting function**

```
 void sorting ()
{
        system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t");
    t();
    printf("\n");
    struct records student[1000];

    char fname[15];
    char lname[15],temp[15];
    int id, i, j, n, IDnum;
    ATND = fopen("Student ID Numbers.txt","r+");
        rewind(ATND);
        for (i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++)
        {                                                   //Beginning for loop
            if (fscanf(ATND, "%s %s %d", fname, lname,  &id) != 3)  //Reads the contents of the file
            break;
            //Storing the read data into variables

            student[i].fname = strdup(fname);
            student[i].lname = strdup(lname);
            student[i].id = id;
        }                                                   //Ending the for loop
    fclose(ATND);


    for (j = 1; j < i; j++) 
    {
        for (n = 1; n < i; n++) 
       {    

    if (strcmp(student[n - 1].lname, student[n].lname) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, student[n - 1].lname);
                strcpy(student[n - 1].lname, student[n].lname);
                strcpy(student[n].lname, temp);

            strcpy(temp, student[n - 1].fname);
            strcpy(student[n - 1].fname, student[n].fname);
            strcpy(student[n].fname, temp);

}
}
}


        for (j=0; j < i; j++)
    {
    //  if(student[j].id == IDnum)
    //  {

        //  printf("\nID number: %d", student[j].id);
        //  printf("\nName: %s %s\n", student[j].fname, student[j].lname);
    printf("%-15s %-20s %-20d", student[j].fname, student[j].lname,  student[j].id);

        }
//  }
}
```

Comment: If you know how to compare the student name why can't you apply the same technique with the student number? If you require help you need to explain exactly what it is that is preventing you from progressing your code.

Comment: You need to swap the `id`, for example `int x=student[n-1].id; student[n-1].id=student[n].id; student[n].id=x;`

Comment: Im very sorry about that. I actually tried the exact same method @user3386109 mentioned above, however, the id numbers still weren't sorting

Comment: You should be using full structure assignment instead of those `strcpy` calls, which aren't required anyway from the looks of it, as both `fname` and `lname` are `char*`, not arrays. Regardless, [something like this](http://pastebin.com/vCkxgf43).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing lname, compare id.
`if (strcmp(student[n - 1].id, student[n].id) > 0)`